# Error Sliding Menu

Tags: android, inflate, slidingmenu

I create a Sliding Menu, but the log shows me the mesage:

```
 08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testeslidingmenuagvdnc/com.example.testeslidingmenuagvdnc.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:457)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.setMenu(SlidingMenu.java:375)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at com.example.testeslidingmenuagvdnc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  ... 11 more
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.testeslidingmenuagvdnc.SlidingMenuFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:493)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:468)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4081)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
08-13 18:19:08.064: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  ... 18 more
```

Sliding Menu

```
 public class SlidingMenuFragment extends Fragment implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener {

        private ExpandableListView sectionListView;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            List<Section> sectionList = createMenu();

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingmenu_fragment, container, false);
            this.sectionListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.slidingmenu_view);
            this.sectionListView.setGroupIndicator(null);

            SectionListAdapter sectionListAdapter = new SectionListAdapter(this.getActivity(), sectionList);
            this.sectionListView.setAdapter(sectionListAdapter); 

            this.sectionListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                    return true;
                  }
                });

            this.sectionListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);

            int count = sectionListAdapter.getGroupCount();
            for (int position = 0; position < count; position++) {
                this.sectionListView.expandGroup(position);
            }

            return view;
        }

        private List<Section> createMenu() {
            List<Section> sectionList = new ArrayList<Section>();

            Section oDemoSection = new Section("Demos");
            oDemoSection.addSectionItem(101,"List/Detail (Fragment)", "slidingmenu_friends");
            oDemoSection.addSectionItem(102, "Airport (AsyncTask)", "slidingmenu_airport");

            Section oGeneralSection = new Section("General");
            oGeneralSection.addSectionItem(201, "Settings", "slidingmenu_settings");
            oGeneralSection.addSectionItem(202, "Rate this app", "slidingmenu_rating");
            oGeneralSection.addSectionItem(203, "Eula", "slidingmenu_eula");
            oGeneralSection.addSectionItem(204, "Quit", "slidingmenu_quit");

            sectionList.add(oDemoSection);
            sectionList.add(oGeneralSection);
            return sectionList;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            switch ((int)id) {
            case 101:
                //TODO
                break;
            case 102:
                //TODO
                break;
            case 201:
                //TODO
                break;
            case 202:
                //TODO
                break;
            case 203:
                //TODO
                break;
            case 204:
                //TODO
                break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

My Activity:

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    private SlidingMenu slidingMenu;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    slidingMenu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_shadow_width);
    slidingMenu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.slidingmenu_shadow);
    slidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if ( slidingMenu.isMenuShowing()) {
        slidingMenu.toggle();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        this.slidingMenu.toggle();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        this.slidingMenu.toggle();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

XML of Activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

XML SliderMenu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@color/purple_dark" >

     <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/slidingmenu_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

XML item of ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/slidingmenu_list_selector_background">

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/slidingmenu_sectionitem_icon"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/slidingmenu_sectionitem_label"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/slidingmenu_sectionitem_icon"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:text="TextView"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think your error log contains a `Caused by` part

Comment: Post the code in your XML layout for the fragment and activity. Post a full stack trace.

Comment: If you are using jfeinstein10 - SlidingMenu library. You are approaching the SlidingMenu in an incorrect way. The MainActivity class needs to extend SlidingActivity class. Also if you want to run Fragments on your MainActivity, then you need to extend SlidingFragmentActivity instead of SlidingActivity .

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your class ***SlidingMenuFragment*** so it extends **SherlockFragment**
if you look at the source code of the SlidingMenu class you can see it extends "SherlockFragmentActivity"